# Applying random float value to shader sine wave for one pi(for example: to make waving water, but each wave is different size)

Tags: unity-game-engine, graphics, shader, hlsl, vertex-shader

I got a task to make. I need to create waving water shader script with each wave to be a random size. I tried to create it by creating C# script to pass a random value to shader script and then multiply my vertex input by that value, but when I do so, as expected all values of Y are multiplied and that's not result I want. I need to multiply a specific one wave (one pi) of the sine wave to increase only one wave, not all y points. Also random value is changing too fast, but I can fixed that by my self.

I am a newbie in shader scripting so that's as far as I went:

```
Shader "Custom/Waves"
{
    Properties{
        _Color("Color", Color) = (0, 0, 0, 1)
        _Strength("Strength", Range(0, 2)) = 1.0
        _Speed("Speed", Range(-200,200)) = 100
    }

        SubShader{
        Tags{
        "RenderType" = "transparent"
        }
        Pass{

        Cull Off

        CGPROGRAM
        #pragma vertex vertexFunc
        #pragma fragment fragFunc

        float4 _Color;
        float _Strength;
        float _Speed;

        struct vertexInput {
            float4 vertex : POSITION;
        };

        struct vertexOutput {
            float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
        };



        vertexOutput vertexFunc(vertexInput v) {
            vertexOutput o;

            float4 worldPos = mul(unity_ObjectToWorld, v.vertex);
            float a = 1;
            float displacement = (cos(worldPos.y) + cos(worldPos.x + _Speed * _Time.y));
            worldPos.y = worldPos.y + (displacement * _Strength);
            o.pos = mul(UNITY_MATRIX_VP, worldPos);
            return o;
        }

        float4 fragFunc(vertexOutput IN) : COLOR{
            return _Color;
        }

            ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```

C# script for random value:

```
public class RandomValue: MonoBehaviour
{
    public Material material;
    public float Max = 2.0f;

    // Start is called before the first frame update


    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        float number = Random.Range(0.0f, Max);
        material.SetFloat("_Strength", number);
    }
}
```

Can someone explain me how to apply random value to a specific part of sine wave which is moving in x vertex.

Comment: I'm not really sure if I understand but maybe `if (worldPos.x > some_value1 && worldPos.x < some_value2) worldPos.y = worldPos.y + (displacement * _Strength);` ? Then you could use `step` or `>=` to avoid the branching. see [here](https://forum.unity.com/threads/step-vs-operator.604873/) or [here](https://forum.unity.com/threads/if-statements-in-fragment.179707/) for some examples of that.

Comment: @Ruzihm That would help, but is there a way to make that step move in the same speed and in the same position as moving one wave. Becouse if I apply your solution, step will only in one place and not moving together with one wave of sine. I am really sorry for my bad english if you cant undestand me thats okay. I should go learn english instead of shaders -.-

Comment: It's ok. Most native English speakers have trouble describing things like waves and 3d. The shader is going to need to know which segment needs to be increased, so you can give it the time when the pulse begins. Try adding a `float  _PulseTime` then setting it with `material.SetFloat("_PulseTime", Time.timeSinceLevelLoad);` then in the shader `if (abs( (worldPos.x + _Time.y) - (_PulseTime + some_value1) ) < some_value2) worldPos.y = worldPos.y + (displacement * _Strength);` where `some_value1` determines where along x the pulse starts and `some_value2` determines the width of the pulse.

Comment: If it works let me know, so I can write a proper answer

Comment: @Ruzihm that's not a solution for the thing that I want to achieve, but your answer gave me a basic idea how I should customize my script to make it work how I want. Thank you!!!

Comment: Glad I helped! Please feel free to [write an answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) once you have something that works.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the amplitude of individual waves is quite hard and requires you to create some kind of function which lets you operate on individual wave peaks. This is easy enough when your wave depends on a single coordinate, but gets more complicated when the peaks also depend on the cosine of the Y value (did you mean to use Z? Y is up in Unity!). I think that generally you are just as well off adding some extra levels of randomness to your waves overall to make it look more varied and dynamic.

One option is to use a procedural noise field and use the vertex X/Z position as UV coordinates. You can multiply this with your sine value to get some variation, and even offset the noise UVs by time to get an extra dimension of motion. There is a nice implementation of gradient noise here:

https://www.shadertoy.com/view/XdXGW8

When it comes to simulating multiple waves in an ocean though, the most common method is to use Fast Fourier Transform to simulate the sum of thousands of wave frequencies and amplitudes at a low computational cost. This is what most AAA games use. There is some engineer-level math involved, but there are some resources and GitHub projects online to check out. Typically, you do the fourier transform in a compute shader or on the GPU, and then send them to the vertex/fragment shader in the shape of a texture.

https://arm-software.github.io/opengl-es-sdk-for-android/ocean_f_f_t.html

https://www.keithlantz.net/2011/11/ocean-simulation-part-two-using-the-fast-fourier-transform/